# Product id in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, prestashop

I don't have much experience in js. I want to create variable productId which has got a product ID and then this variable use in

```
$('#quantity_wanted_'+ productId +').change();
```

How can I do this ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">// The button to increment the product value
    //var allowBuyWhenOutOfStock = false;

    $(document).on('click', '.product_quantity_up', function(e){
        var productId = 6;
        e.preventDefault();
        fieldName = $(this).data('field-qty');
        var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
        if (!allowBuyWhenOutOfStock && quantityAvailable > 0)
            quantityAvailableT = quantityAvailable;
        else
            quantityAvailableT = 100000000;
        if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal < quantityAvailableT)
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1).trigger('keyup');
        else
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(quantityAvailableT);

        $('#quantity_wanted_'+ productId +').change();
    });
    // The button to decrement the product value
    $(document).on('click', '.product_quantity_down', function(e){
        var productId = 7;
        e.preventDefault();
        fieldName = $(this).data('field-qty');
        var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
        if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 1)
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal - 1).trigger('keyup');
        else
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(1);

        $('#quantity_wanted_'+productId+').change();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please explain further

Comment: I don't know how to read variable from php and use it in javascript.

Comment: You shouldn't have `+'` after `productId`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Smarty you can define javascript variable.

If you look at the bottom of `product.tpl` file you will see this kind of line :

```
{addJsDef customizationId=$id_customization}
{addJsDef customizationFields=$customizationFields}
{addJsDef default_eco_tax=$product->ecotax|floatval}
```

Those variables are put in the head section of your websites before loading javascript files. So its accessible from any javascript file.

You can then add your `productId` variable at the end of the `product.tpl` template with the other one:

```
{addJsDef productId=$product->id}
```

On my theme a variable named `id_product` already exists, it might be available in your theme also:

```
{addJsDef id_product=$product->id|intval}
```

Comment: Good to know. I have this code in product-list.tpl where are many products. When I create/set {addJsDef id_product=$product->id|intval} I got 0. Check the link http://prestashop.suszek.info/3-women

Answer (score 0):

You need to create/set `productId` in TPL:

```
{addJsDef productId=$id_product}
```

Good luck.